# Creating a C++ console application in Visual Studio on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio

It seems like I'm not able to create a C++ console application using Visual Studio on macOS.

I did a little bit of research and seems that this isn't possible on macOS yet.

Is there some package I can install to make it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio for Mac is basically a re-branded Xamarin Studio. it currently only supports C# and F# from the looks of it. (Silly, I know)